# What's the expectation of a sum of product of couples of random variables?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a sample of n elements X=x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub> and I should check the correlation between X and a bogus sample Y made of the same observations of X but delayed of one element so that y<sub>i</sub> = x<sub>i+1</sub> (and n+1=1 so that y<sub>n</sub>=x<sub>1</sub>); I should rely on the statistics: $$R=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i X_{i+1}$$(where X<sub>i</sub> is the random variable "value of the i<sup>th</sup> observation" that takes x<sub>i</sub> as one of its possible values) as a measure of correlation in order to test the randomness of the observations. Now, by means of which mathematical passages my textbook comes to the equation: $$E[R] = \frac{(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)^2-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}{n-1}?$$ (no specification is given for the mean and variance of the population).

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. What are the $x_i$? And if you don't know the mean of the $X_i$ I don't think it's possible to calculate the mean of $R$. Are you sure you've copied everything down properly? Make sure you differentiate between capitalized and uncapitalized variables.

Comment: $\frac{(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)^2-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}{n-1}$ will never be positive, while  $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i x_{i+1}$ will often be positive unless $\bar x=0$.  Are you dealing with residuals here?